# Best method to automate inputs to create templates? (Userforms?)

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I'm looking to create a template for technical documents. I would like to be able to put it several variables one time using something like a user form and have multiple areas within the document populated. I saw one method of using bookmarks to do so and it seemed decent but from what I could tell you could not use the same bookmark more than once. For example, I have a PartNumber field on every header (my header is different for each section). From what I saw with the bookmark method I would have to make a new bookmark for every place I want to use the PartNumber variable instead of inserting a repeating bookmark. This makes the VBA lengthy and makes the maintenance of the template more tedious. Is there an easier or cleaner way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bookmarks you can use Ref fields (Insert>Quick Parts>Field) to display the bookmarked text in other parts of the document.

Alternatively you could research using CustomXML parts and mapped content controls (the more modern method).

Both methods can be achieved with or without using a User Form.